# How to show a 100% Stacked Area Chart in JavaFx?

Tags: javafx

I'm new to JavaFx, but would like to use it to draw some charts in my existing Swing application.

In Excel there is a *Stacked Area Chart* and a *100% Stacked Area Chart*.
The stacked area chart is simple enough in JavaFx using StackedAreaChart, but what would be the best way to show a 100% Stacked Area Chart?

(Unfortunately I don't have enough points to post an image showing the two charts... The idea behind the 100% Stacked Area Chart is to have the y-axis represent the percentages, 0-100%, instead of the data values.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by manually scaling the data (from 0%-100%) before sending it to the JavaFX chart. It's not the solution I hoped for, but does the job.